# Running following circuit in under 18mA and 15-20V.

Tags: transformer, driver, low-power

[image]

So i build above circuit to drive a high frequency transformer that have Primary 10 Turns, Feedback 8 Turns, and Secondary winding of 1350 turns.It works great for my application with 7V input and drawing .2-3A current. But i was wondering if i could bring it down to work under 15-20V and 18mA power supply. Also is there anyway to limit current drawing through the circuit. Q1 is MJE182 - NPN transistor.

Comment: Are you allowed to increase the primary turns? Does it mattter that you'll get less output power?

Comment: @brian I can't change primary turns. On the output side i am looking for high voltage and low current.